# Can you not append integers to list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook, append

I am writing python in jupyter and it is not letting me append an integer

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9f16fe42f950> in <module>
      5     else:
      6 
----> 7         list.append(b)
      8         continue

TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

This is what it is showing. This is the code:

```
while True: 
    b = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if input =='done':
        break
    else:
        
        list.append(b)
        continue
```

Comment: Of course you can. However, `list` is the class `list`. It is a class object, not a list object. What did you expect `list.append(b)` to do? You haven't created a list anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

`list` is a class, not an instance. If you want to use a list, instantiate it first.

```py
l = list() # or l = []
l.append(...)
```